# A first differenced time series

Tags: time-series

I have differenced my time series because is not stationary.Now in my model I will use this time series, but I have a value less.Is this correct?Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

- If your original series has one data point, you can't difference it.
- If your original series has two data points $y_1, y_2$, your differenced series has one: $y_2-y_1$.
- If your original series has three data points $y_1, y_2, y_3$, your differenced series has two: $y_2-y_1, y_3-y_2$.

And so forth. Each time you take differences, you lose one data point. (If you difference twice, you lose two points.)

Comment: Thank you very much.My original data has 24 observation (from the year 1994-2017) and after differencing I obtain 23.But can I insert this data in my model, if the other time series have 24 observations?

Comment: It depends on the relationship between the other data and the series you are differencing. If you believe that a predictor's value in 1994 has an impact on the increment of the focal series (the one you are differencing) between 1994 and 1995, then include the values of the predictor for 1994-2016 to model the differences in your focal series.

Comment: Dear Stephan,thank you for helping me and sorry for my english(is not very good). I should insert the differencing time series in the model, but my question is: is correct having 23 observations, when other time series have 24?For example, in "r" when I use to find the lag order, using VAR select function, and I insert my data, for the time series that I am differencing "r" shows the message:missing data (for example: Error in VARselect(variablat4, lag.max = 10, type = c("none")) : NAs in y.)

Comment: Maybe I have to use the function na.omit for non having missing data?